# F# Result Unit Test Fails without type annotation - Can I avoid the type annotation in this case?

Tags: types, f#, annotations

I'm doing some F# exercises and the task is to implement a function called `clean` which takes a string input and returns a parsed number.

```
let clean input = 
    input
    |> Seq.filter Char.IsDigit
    |> Seq.fold (fun acc cur ->
                    if acc = "" && cur = '1' then
                        acc
                    else acc + string cur) ""
    |> uint64
    |> Ok
```

This is my temporary solution. But the unit test bellow failed:

```
[<Fact>]
let ``Cleans the number`` () =
    let expected: Result<uint64,string> = Ok 2234567890UL
    let parsed = clean "(223) 456-7890"
    parsed |> should equal expected
```

It fails:

> FsUnit.Xunit+MatchException : Exception of type
>   'FsUnit.Xunit+MatchException' was thrown. Expected: Equals Ok
>   2234567890UL Actual:   was
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpResult`2[System.UInt64,System.Object]
>
>   at FsUnit.Xunit.Assert.That.Static[a](a actual, IMatcher`1 matcher)
>   at PhoneNumberTest.Cleans numbers with dots() in

So I added an type annotation: `let clean input: Result<uint64,string> // function body is the same`

Can I avoid the type annotation and what is the technical reason that the first solution failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the type annotation, your `clean` function is inferred to have the generic type `seq<char> -> Result<uint64,'a>`, so in the case you need the type annotation.

The reason for the compiler to infer a generic type is that you always return the `OK` branch of the `Result<'ok,'error>` type.

As also the name of your function suggest, maybe `Result` is not the most sutiable return type here?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that compiler cannot infer the type that your `Result` would have in the case of a failure from just the success value `Ok 2234567890UL`. When it does not know, it just uses `obj` and so the default inferred type is `Result<uint64, obj>`. Comparing objects of different types is always `false`.

This is somewhat unfortunate, because you are comparing the two values and so, they have to have the same type. The `FsUnit` library which provides `should` and `equal` operations is not strictly typed and allows you to compare values of different types. You can write:

```
1 |> should equal "1"
```

There is a [library `FsUnitTyped`](https://fsprojects.github.io/FsUnit/FsUnitTyped.html) which implements a typed version of FsUnit. I don't have experience with this, but it looks like you could use it and write:

```
[<Fact>]
let ``Cleans the number`` () =
    let expected = Ok 2234567890UL
    let parsed = clean "(223) 456-7890"
    parsed |> shouldEqual expected
```

This would solve your problem - the compiler could infer that the type of `expected` has to be the same as the type of `parsed`, so it would automatically use the correct type.

Comment: Ah thanks for the explanation. `1 |> should equal "1"` is really weird for unit tests not to fail